# Arabic retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am trying to use TCPDF library to have a PDF file that supports Arabic letters. I have created a table and get the data from MYSQL database.

```
 <?php

 // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
 require_once('TCPDF/config/tcpdf_config.php');

 require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');


class PDF extends TCPDF{ 

var $tablewidths; 
 var $headerset; 
 var $footerset; 



 function morepagestable($lineheight=8) { 
// some things to set and 'remember' 
$l = $this->lMargin*2; 
$startheight = $h = $this->GetY(); 
$startpage = $currpage = $this->page; 

// calculate the whole width 
foreach($this->tablewidths as $width) { 
    $fullwidth += $width; 
} 

// Now let's start to write the table 
$row = 0; 
while($data=mysql_fetch_row($this->results)) { 
    $this->page = $currpage; 
    // write the horizontal borders 
    $this->Line($l,$h,$fullwidth+$l,$h); 
    // write the content and remember the height of the highest col 
    foreach($data as $col => $txt) { 

        $this->page = $currpage; 
        $this->SetXY($l,$h); 
        $this->MultiCell($this->tablewidths[$col],$lineheight,$txt,0,$this->colAlign[$col]); 

        $l += $this->tablewidths[$col]; 

        if($tmpheight[$row.'-'.$this->page] < $this->GetY()) { 
            $tmpheight[$row.'-'.$this->page] = $this->GetY(); 
        } 
        if($this->page > $maxpage) 
            $maxpage = $this->page; 
        unset($data[$col]); 
    } 
    // get the height we were in the last used page 
    $h = $tmpheight[$row.'-'.$maxpage]; 
    // set the "pointer" to the left margin 
    $l = $this->lMargin*2; 
    // set the $currpage to the last page 
    $currpage = $maxpage; 
    unset($datas[$row]); 
    $row++ ; 
} 
// draw the borders 
// we start adding a horizontal line on the last page 
$this->page = $maxpage; 
$this->Line($l,$h,$fullwidth+$l,$h); 
// now we start at the top of the document and walk down 
for($i = $startpage; $i <= $maxpage; $i++) { 
    $this->page = $i; 
    $l = $this->lMargin*2; 
    $t = ($i == $startpage) ? $startheight : $this->tMargin; 
    $lh = ($i == $maxpage) ? $h : $this->h-$this->bMargin; 
    $this->Line($l,$t,$l,$lh); 
    foreach($this->tablewidths as $width) { 
        $l += $width; 
        $this->Line($l,$t,$l,$lh); 
    } 
} 
// set it to the last page, if not it'll cause some problems 
$this->page = $maxpage; 
} 



 connect($host='xxxx',$username='xxxx',$passwd='xxxx',$db='xxxxx') 
{ 
$this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$passwd) or die( mysql_error() ); 
mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) or die( mysql_error() ); 
return true; 
   } 

   function query($query){ 
$this->results = mysql_query($query,$this->conn); 
$this->numFields = mysql_num_fields($this->results); 
   } 

 function mysql_report($query,$dump=false,$attr=array()){

foreach($attr as $key=>$val){ 
    $this->$key = $val ; 
} 

$this->query($query); 

// if column widths not set 
if(!isset($this->tablewidths)){ 

    // starting col width 
    $this->sColWidth = (($this->w-$this->lMargin*2-$this->rMargin))/$this->numFields; 

    // loop through results header and set initial col widths/ titles/ alignment 
    // if a col title is less than the starting col width / reduce that column size 
    for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
        $stringWidth = $this->getstringwidth(mysql_field_name($this->results,$i)) + 8 ; 
        if( ($stringWidth) < $this->sColWidth){ 
            $colFits[$i] = $stringWidth ; 
            // set any column titles less than the start width to the column title width 
        } 
        $this->colTitles[$i] = mysql_field_name($this->results,$i) ; 
        switch (mysql_field_type($this->results,$i)){ 
            case 'int': 
                $this->colAlign[$i] = 'L'; 
                break; 
            default: 
                $this->colAlign[$i] = 'L'; 
        } 
    } 

    // loop through the data, any column whose contents is bigger that the col size is 
    // resized 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($this->results)){ 
        foreach($colFits as $key=>$val){ 
            $stringWidth = $this->getstringwidth($row[$key]) + 6 ; 
            if( ($stringWidth) > $this->sColWidth ){ 
                // any col where row is bigger than the start width is now discarded 
                unset($colFits[$key]); 
            }else{ 
                // if text is not bigger than the current column width setting enlarge the column 
                if( ($stringWidth) > $val ){ 
                    $colFits[$key] = ($stringWidth) ; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    foreach($colFits as $key=>$val){ 
        // set fitted columns to smallest size 
        $this->tablewidths[$key] = $val; 
        // to work out how much (if any) space has been freed up 
        $totAlreadyFitted += $val; 
    } 

    $surplus = (sizeof($colFits)*$this->sColWidth) - ($totAlreadyFitted); 
    for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
        if(!in_array($i,array_keys($colFits))){ 
            $this->tablewidths[$i] = $this->sColWidth + ($surplus/(($this->numFields)-sizeof($colFits))); 
        } 
    } 

    ksort($this->tablewidths); 

    if($dump){ 
        Header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
        for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
            if(strlen(mysql_field_name($this->results,$i))>$flength){ 
                $flength = strlen(mysql_field_name($this->results,$i)); 
            } 
        } 
        switch($this->k){ 
            case 72/25.4: 
                $unit = 'millimeters'; 
                break; 
            case 72/2.54: 
                $unit = 'centimeters'; 
                break; 
            case 72: 
                $unit = 'inches'; 
                break; 
            default: 
                $unit = 'points'; 
        } 
        print "All measurements in $unit\n\n"; 
        for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
            printf("%-{$flength}s : %-10s : %10f\n", 
                mysql_field_name($this->results,$i), 
                mysql_field_type($this->results,$i), 
                $this->tablewidths[$i] ); 
        } 
        print "\n\n"; 
        print "\$pdf->tablewidths=\n\tarray(\n\t\t"; 
        for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
            ($i<($this->numFields-1)) ? 
            print $this->tablewidths[$i].", /* ".mysql_field_name($this->results,$i)." */ \n\t\t": 
            print $this->tablewidths[$i]." /* ".mysql_field_name($this->results,$i)." */\n\t\t"; 
        } 
        print "\n\t);\n"; 
        exit; 
    } 

} else { // end of if tablewidths not defined 

    for($i=0;$i<$this->numFields;$i++){ 
        $this->colTitles[$i] = mysql_field_name($this->results,$i) ; 
        switch (mysql_field_type($this->results,$i)){ 
            case 'int': 
                $this->colAlign[$i] = 'R'; 
                break; 
            default: 
                $this->colAlign[$i] = 'L'; 
        } 
    } 
} 

mysql_data_seek($this->results,0); 
$this->Open(); 
$this->setY($this->tMargin); 
$this->AddPage(); 
$this->morepagestable($this->FontSizePt); 
$this->Output(); 
 } 

 } 

   $pdf = new PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION,PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,true, 'UTF-   8', false); 
   $pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 14, '', false);


 $pdf->connect('xxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 
  $attr=array('titleFontSize'=>24,'titleText'=>'THIS IS MY PDF FILE'); 
   $pdf->mysql_report("SELECT * FROM Student_Table",false,$attr); 


  ?>
```

I am OK with the table that is created with my code. The Arabic data retrieved is as the following?how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very simple bro, you need to choose the correct database encoding and do the query with it , but before going for that , I think this is my duty to tell you **YOU DON'T HAVE TO USE "mysql" YOU HAVE TO USE "mysqli"** ,now let us solve the problem :

1. set your database encoding to (**utf8_general_ci**). take a backup don't forget all the old stuff will be destroyed if you change the charset of the database do this if it's new or empty
2. after mysqli connect do this **$db->set_charset("utf8");** or if you still
   want to work with mysql use this **mysql_set_charset("utf8");**

   Here is the edited code:

   ```
       connect($host='xxxx',$username='xxxx',$passwd='xxxx',$db='xxxxx') 
           { 
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$passwd) or die( mysql_error() ); 
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) or die( mysql_error() ); 


         mysql_set_charset("utf8");

        return true; 
        }
   ```

But, like what i told you , you did it in wrong way , use mysqli and do it with full OOP not some time and in other Not !

Comment: thank you. It works. Thanks for the advise, when I created my database I did made it utf_general_ci. About backup sure thing, I make it between time to time.